# Activate highlight code in haskell mode

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

I installed haskell-mode in order to have highlighted code when editing *.hs files.

I have added the following line to my init.el file:

```
(load "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/haskell-mode/haskell-package.el")
```

As it can be understand from the manual https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/wiki/Syntax-highlighting, the code should be highlited automatically by adding this line, right?

I have also added the line

```
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indentation)
```

into my init.el file just to see if anithing changes but still I get nothing for haskell code.

Comment: Is haskell mode enabled? The mode is usually displayed at the bottom of each buffer. If it isn't, enable it (`M-x haskell-mode`) to see if it works.

Comment: it returns `[No match]`, how can I overcome this?

Comment: You don't have haskell mode installed. The easiest way of doing this is using package.el. The instructions [here](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode) are very straightforward.

Comment: It dones't work either, I have the lines `(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/haskell-mode/")
(load "/someotherpath/ESS/lisp/ess-site.el")
(load "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/haskell-mode/haskell-package.el")
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indentation)`

ESS is used by julia and works fine, but the same trick with package.el doesn't work

Comment: now it says: `Symbol's value as variable is void: haskell-font-lock-choose-keywords`

Comment: For all you that are lost as me, follow the instructions in https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode. (I didn't do the last make all since all worked before smoothly.)

Answer (score 1):

It is best to use MELPA to install haskell-mode. Everything should work out of the box when you use MELPA. Instructions to get going with haskell-mode are in the manual:

http://haskell.github.io/haskell-mode/manual/latest/Getting-Started.html#Getting-Started